# Removing a manually installed package and now reporting not installed but won't install

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, mono

I manually compiled mono from the /tmp directory (4.9.1) and found that it was too unstable for me, so wanted to revert back to the install from the repos. I foolishly did a reboot before doing this, so the compiled code in /tmp had gone. So, I thought I'd remove the directory of where mono is installed and mark the package mono-complete as being automatically installed again.

(Un)Surprisingly, this did not work. Now, if I do a `which mono` it reports that it isn't installed. If I `mono` I get the same message. However, when I do an `apt install mono-complete` or `mono-devel` it reports `mono-complete is already the newest version`.

I have checked in the `env` and there is no reference to mono.

How can I sort this mess out and get back to being able to install mono from packages.

Comment: Please restart your system and try again...

Comment: I did restart, several times infact. I ran purge a few times for mono-complete, mono-runtime and mono-devel just to be sure, then restarted. I found I could then install from the repo and everything seems to be fine for now!

Comment: Mark the mono-complete package as not installed. Then search for every file and folder named mono at /usr/local and remove them. Now reinstall mono-complete from apt. And first of all: backup.